# Arduino Serial Communication double precision problem

Tags: arduino

I am using Arduino Serial Communication to input numbers into Arduino program.

But whenever I insert float or double numbers into arduino serial com,

precision of number is not accurate to string value.

Here is picture to help explain what is going on.

[image]

String is what i put into serial input, and double is what i get when i convert the number into double.

```
String GPSNumCor1;
double GPSNumCor;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin (9600);
  Serial.println("What is the number of your GPS Coordinate?  ");
  while (Serial.available() == 0);
  GPSNumCor1 = Serial.readString();
  GPSNumCor=GPSNumCor1.toDouble();
  Serial.print("String: ");
  Serial.println(GPSNumCor1);
  Serial.print("Double: ");
  Serial.println(GPSNumCor,15);
}
```

As far as I know, this should do the job, based on the youtube video I followed from here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIa_QZWIonQ

Maybe it fails because there are too many decimal places in number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the AVR Arduinos such as Arduino Uno, `double` is the same thing as `float` and has 32bit ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)). All fixed-size floating-point datatypes only support limited precision. 32bit floating-point has 7-8 decimal places of precision, which fits your `33.33333061...`. The digits that come after all the `3`s are the result of converting the binary number back to decimal. So, without a (complex/slow) multi-precision floating-point library, you won't be able to process such high-precision numbers on an AVR Arduino without loosing some digits.

Comment: If i use arduino mega, would it be fine?

Comment: No, that uses an AVR as well. The Arduino Due is based on an ARM Cortex-M3, where the GCC can use 64bit `double` (still slow due to lack of FPU). Or think about whether you *really* need all that precision or whether 7-8 digits suffice. What precision do you need?

Comment: I want to input GPS coordinate in decimal within half meter range, so I need 0.0000001 at least.

Comment: Do you actually want to do calculations with these numbers (how many, how fast?) or just log them?

Comment: Once I input the number, I will calculate area, then add approximately 0.0000001 to 0.0000005 in array.  This will be used in my drone

Comment: It would not require very fast calculation, because it is ground based drone.

Comment: Then the easiest way is probably to just use an Arduino Due. It would be possible to do `double` calculations on an AVR, but quick googling didn't find a ready-to-use solution for that, except using the IAR compiler, which doesn't work with Arduino.

Comment: An alternative would be to manually convert the number into an `int64_t` based fixed point number.

Comment: Another alternative is to work relative to given coordinates instead of global GPS coordinates. But again, `float` is not a solution, but a problem